# VPN connection issue

Tags: networking, vpn, connection

I have laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I created L2TP connection and I see a successful label connection for a short time, then the connection is broken. So I tried connecting with some settings on another laptop, and all works well.

Using the Router (Zyxel USG100) log I do not see any difference between a successful and failed connection. Also, I tried to connect to VPN using Mobile hotspot. It means: The router VPN settings and laptop connection are correct.

I think that the issue in the laptop settings like network manager, or something else.

Also I compared 2 syslog from successful and wrong connections. I need to solve this issue in the laptop with wrong connection.

Log below:

Jul 26 14:07:38  NetworkManager[1151]:   [1658833658.4708] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9" name="office" pid=2814 uid=1000 result="success"

Jul 26 14:07:38  nm-l2tp-service[7356]: Check port 1701

Jul 26 14:07:38  nm-l2tp-service[7356]: Can't bind to port 1701

Jul 26 14:07:38  NetworkManager[7371]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec failed: starter is not running

Jul 26 14:07:40  NetworkManager[7368]: Starting strongSwan 5.9.5 IPsec [starter]...

Jul 26 14:07:40  NetworkManager[7368]: Loading config setup

Jul 26 14:07:40  NetworkManager[7368]: Loading conn 'be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.5, Linux 5.15.0-41-generic, x86_64)

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[LIB] providers loaded by OpenSSL: legacy default

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/cacerts'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/aacerts'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/ipsec.d/acerts'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/ipsec.d/crls'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[LIB] dropped capabilities, running as uid 0, gid 0

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9'

Jul 26 14:07:40  charon: 05[CFG] added configuration 'be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9'

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 07[CFG] rereading secrets

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 07[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.secrets'

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 07[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.nm-l2tp.secrets'

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 07[CFG]   loaded IKE secret for %any

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 09[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9'

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 11[IKE] initiating Main Mode IKE_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9[1] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 11[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 11[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] (532 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] to 192.168.3.16[500] (248 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[ENC] parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V V ]

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: f7:58:f2:26:68:75:0f:03:b0:8d:f6:eb:e1:d0:04:03

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: af:ca:d7:13:68:a1:f1:c9:6b:86:96:fc:77:57

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02 vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[IKE] received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03 vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[IKE] received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[IKE] received XAuth vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[IKE] received DPD vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[ENC] received unknown vendor ID: af:ca:d7:13:68:a1:f1:c9:6b:86:96:fc:77:57

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[CFG] selected proposal: IKE:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]

Jul 26 14:07:41  charon: 12[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] (244 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:42  charon: 13[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] to 192.168.3.16[500] (228 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:42  charon: 13[ENC] parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]

Jul 26 14:07:42  charon: 13[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives

Jul 26 14:07:42  charon: 13[ENC] generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH ]

Jul 26 14:07:42  charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (68 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 14[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (68 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 14[ENC] parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 14[IKE] IKE_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9[1] established between 192.168.3.16[192.168.3.16]...-IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[-IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-]

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 14[IKE] scheduling reauthentication in 10068s

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 14[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 10608s

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 14[ENC] generating QUICK_MODE request 575456838 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (244 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 15[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (172 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 15[ENC] parsed QUICK_MODE response 575456838 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 15[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/NO_EXT_SEQ

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 15[IKE] CHILD_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9{1} established with SPIs c1839f61_i 6f7b78c9_o and TS 192.168.3.16/32[udp] === -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-/32[udp/l2f]

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 15[ENC] generating QUICK_MODE request 575456838 [ HASH ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: initiating Main Mode IKE_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9[1] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] (532 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] to 192.168.3.16[500] (248 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V V V V V V V V ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received unknown vendor ID: f7:58:f2:26:68:75:0f:03:b0:8d:f6:eb:e1:d0:04:03

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received unknown vendor ID: af:ca:d7:13:68:a1:f1:c9:6b:86:96:fc:77:57

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02 vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03 vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received NAT-T (RFC 3947) vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received XAuth vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received DPD vendor ID

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received unknown vendor ID: af:ca:d7:13:68:a1:f1:c9:6b:86:96:fc:77:57

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: selected proposal: IKE:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/PRF_HMAC_SHA1/MODP_1024

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] (244 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[500] to 192.168.3.16[500] (228 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (68 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (68 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: IKE_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9[1] established between 192.168.3.16[192.168.3.16]...-IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[-IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: scheduling reauthentication in 10068s

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: maximum IKE_SA lifetime 10608s

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: generating QUICK_MODE request 575456838 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (244 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (172 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: parsed QUICK_MODE response 575456838 [ HASH SA No ID ID NAT-OA NAT-OA ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: selected proposal: ESP:3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/NO_EXT_SEQ

Jul 26 14:07:43  charon: 15[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (60 bytes)

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: CHILD_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9{1} established with SPIs c1839f61_i 6f7b78c9_o and TS 192.168.3.16/32[udp] === -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-/32[udp/l2f]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: generating QUICK_MODE request 575456838 [ HASH ]

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7409]: connection 'be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9' established successfully

Jul 26 14:07:43  nm-l2tp-service[7356]: xl2tpd started with pid 7415

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Not looking for kernel SAref support.

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Using l2tp kernel support.

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.16 started on  PID:7415

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Forked again by Xelerance ([www.xelerance.com](http://www.xelerance.com)) (C) 2006-2016

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 43532

Jul 26 14:07:43  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Connecting to host -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-, port 1701

Jul 26 14:07:44  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Connection established to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-, 1701.  Local: 57169, Remote: 33208 (ref=0/0).

Jul 26 14:07:44  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Calling on tunnel 57169

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Call established with -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-, Local: 29440, Remote: 48344, Serial: 1 (ref=0/0)

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: start_pppd: I'm running:

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "plugin"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "pppol2tp.so"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "pppol2tp"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "7"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "passive"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "nodetach"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: ":"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "file"

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: "/run/nm-l2tp-be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9/ppp-options"

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: Plugin pppol2tp.so loaded.

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.9/nm-l2tp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: pppd 2.4.9 started by root, uid 0

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: Using interface ppp0

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: Connect: ppp0 <-->

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1400

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1400

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[1151]:   [1658833665.0792] manager: (ppp0): new Ppp device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)

Jul 26 14:07:45  systemd-udevd[7426]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v249'.

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: PAP authentication succeeded

Jul 26 14:07:45  charon: 07[KNL] 192.168.10.10 appeared on ppp0

Jul 26 14:07:45  charon: 11[KNL] 192.168.10.10 disappeared from ppp0

Jul 26 14:07:45  charon: 13[KNL] 192.168.10.10 appeared on ppp0

Jul 26 14:07:45  charon: 09[KNL] interface ppp0 activated

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: local  IP address 192.168.10.10

Jul 26 14:07:45  pppd[7423]: remote IP address -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[1151]:   [1658833665.4067] device (ppp0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[1151]:   [1658833665.4073] device (ppp0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')

Jul 26 14:07:45  dbus-daemon[1130]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1151 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")

Jul 26 14:07:45  systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...

Jul 26 14:07:45  dbus-daemon[1130]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'

Jul 26 14:07:45  systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.

Jul 26 14:07:45  NetworkManager[1151]:   [1658833665.4635] policy: set 'office' (ppp0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS

Jul 26 14:07:45  systemd[2466]: Stopping Rygel DLNA/UPnP server...

Jul 26 14:07:45  systemd[2466]: Stopped Rygel DLNA/UPnP server.

Jul 26 14:07:55  systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.

Jul 26 14:08:01  charon: 16[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:01  charon: 16[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 130338377 [ HASH N(DPD) ]

Jul 26 14:08:01  charon: 16[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1412089334 [ HASH N(DPD_ACK) ]

Jul 26 14:08:01  charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (92 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:02  charon: 08[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:02  charon: 08[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3470876714 [ HASH N(DPD) ]

Jul 26 14:08:02  charon: 08[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 2779390581 [ HASH N(DPD_ACK) ]

Jul 26 14:08:02  charon: 08[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (92 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:04  charon: 07[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:04  charon: 07[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 208656731 [ HASH N(DPD) ]

Jul 26 14:08:04  charon: 07[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 2727949583 [ HASH N(DPD_ACK) ]

Jul 26 14:08:04  charon: 07[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (92 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:07  charon: 10[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:07  charon: 10[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3422111430 [ HASH N(DPD) ]

Jul 26 14:08:07  charon: 10[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 4099398598 [ HASH N(DPD_ACK) ]

Jul 26 14:08:07  charon: 10[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (92 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:12  charon: 12[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:12  charon: 12[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1849100511 [ HASH N(DPD) ]

Jul 26 14:08:12  charon: 12[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 2216253322 [ HASH N(DPD_ACK) ]

Jul 26 14:08:12  charon: 12[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (92 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:20  charon: 13[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:20  charon: 13[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 178614390 [ HASH N(DPD) ]

Jul 26 14:08:20  charon: 13[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1755402147 [ HASH N(DPD_ACK) ]

Jul 26 14:08:20  charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (92 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).

Jul 26 14:08:22  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).

Jul 26 14:08:25  gnome-shell[2814]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).

Jul 26 14:08:32  ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[2814]: Impossible to send about-to-show to menu: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: error occurred in AboutToShow

Jul 26 14:08:33  charon: 09[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:33  charon: 09[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 2299470299 [ HASH N(DPD) ]

Jul 26 14:08:33  charon: 09[ENC] generating INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3111156825 [ HASH N(DPD_ACK) ]

Jul 26 14:08:33  charon: 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.3.16[4500] to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] (92 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:46  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 33208 (got 3, expected 4)

Jul 26 14:08:46  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: handle_control: bad control packet!

Jul 26 14:08:48  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 33208 (got 3, expected 4)

Jul 26 14:08:48  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: handle_control: bad control packet!

Jul 26 14:08:52  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: check_control: Received out of order control packet on tunnel 33208 (got 3, expected 4)

Jul 26 14:08:52  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: handle_control: bad control packet!

Jul 26 14:08:53  charon: 16[IKE] sending keep alive to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500]

Jul 26 14:08:54  charon: 07[NET] received packet: from -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[4500] to 192.168.3.16[4500] (84 bytes)

Jul 26 14:08:54  charon: 07[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 1171476007 [ HASH D ]

Jul 26 14:08:54  charon: 07[IKE] received DELETE for IKE_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9[1]

Jul 26 14:08:54  charon: 07[IKE] deleting IKE_SA be2ccf02-296c-45a1-bf14-edddc06e78f9[1] between 192.168.3.16[192.168.3.16]...-IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-[-IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-]

Jul 26 14:09:15  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Maximum retries exceeded for tunnel 57169.  Closing.

Jul 26 14:09:15  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Terminating pppd: sending TERM signal to pid 7423

Jul 26 14:09:15  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: Connection 33208 closed to -IP_HIDDEN_FOR_SECURITY-, port 1701 (Timeout)

Jul 26 14:09:15  pppd[7423]: Terminating on signal 15

Jul 26 14:09:15  pppd[7423]: Connect time 1.5 minutes.

Jul 26 14:09:15  pppd[7423]: Sent 991383100 bytes, received 1641 bytes.

Jul 26 14:09:15  charon: 12[KNL] interface ppp0 deactivated

Jul 26 14:09:15  charon: 11[KNL] 192.168.10.10 disappeared from ppp0

Jul 26 14:09:15  NetworkManager[1151]:   [1658833755.8894] device (ppp0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')

Jul 26 14:09:15  pppd[7423]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1400

Jul 26 14:09:15  pppd[7423]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1400

Jul 26 14:09:19  charon: 09[KNL] 192.168.10.10 appeared on ppp0

Jul 26 14:09:21  pppd[7423]: Connection terminated.

Jul 26 14:09:21  charon: 15[KNL] 192.168.10.10 disappeared from ppp0

Jul 26 14:09:21  NetworkManager[7415]: xl2tpd[7415]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received

Jul 26 14:09:21  charon: 16[KNL] interface ppp0 deleted

Jul 26 14:09:21  NetworkManager[7522]: Stopping strongSwan IPsec...

Jul 26 14:09:21  charon: 00[DMN] SIGINT received, shutting down

Jul 26 14:09:21  gnome-shell[2814]: Removing a network device that was not added

Jul 26 14:09:21  pppd[7423]: Modem hangup

Jul 26 14:09:21  pppd[7423]: Exit.

Jul 26 14:09:22  nm-l2tp-service[7356]: ipsec shut down

Jul 26 14:09:22  NetworkManager[1151]:   [1658833762.0056] policy: set 'Rych-H' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS

Jul 26 14:09:22  dbus-daemon[1130]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=1151 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")

Jul 26 14:09:22  systemd[2466]: Starting Rygel DLNA/UPnP server...

Jul 26 14:09:22  systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...

Jul 26 14:09:22  dbus-daemon[1130]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'

Jul 26 14:09:22  systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: Rygel v0.40.3 starting…

Jul 26 14:09:22  systemd[2466]: Started Rygel DLNA/UPnP server.

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: New plugin “MediaExport” available

Jul 26 14:09:22  mx-extract[7547]: rygel-media-export-extract.vala:180: Started with descriptors 3 (in) 4 (out)

Jul 26 14:09:22  mx-extract[7546]: rygel-media-export-extract.vala:180: Started with descriptors 3 (in) 4 (out)

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: “file:///home/undef/Videos” harvested

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: rygel-media-export-harvesting-task.vala:309: Harvesting of file:///home/undef/Videos done in 0,037026

Jul 26 14:09:22  mx-extract[7550]: rygel-media-export-extract.vala:180: Started with descriptors 3 (in) 4 (out)

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: “file:///home/undef/Music” harvested

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: rygel-media-export-harvesting-task.vala:309: Harvesting of file:///home/undef/Music done in 0,041717

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: “file:///home/undef/Pictures” harvested

Jul 26 14:09:22  rygel[7532]: rygel-media-export-harvesting-task.vala:309: Harvesting of file:///home/undef/Pictures done in 0,071632